# Send message in specific channel DiscordJS

Tags: discord.js

So I'm making a discord bot using DiscordJS and I've been having an issue with this specific command which basically sends a message in a specific channel.

That was my original implementation.

```js
const { Interaction, SlashCommandBuilder, ChannelType, PermissionFlagsBits } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('announce')
        .setDescription('Send an announcement to a specific channel.')
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.MentionEveryone)
        .addChannelOption(option => option
            .setName('channel')
            .setDescription('The channel where you want to send the announcement')
            .addChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildText)
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addStringOption(option => option
            .setName('message')
            .setDescription('The announcement message you want to send')
            .setMinLength(1).setMaxLength(1950)
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addBooleanOption(option => option
            .setName('mention_everyone')
            .setDescription('Whether to mention everyone or not')
        )
        .setDMPermission(false),

    /** 
     * @param {Interaction} interaction 
     */
    async execute(interaction) {
        const channel = interaction.options.get('channel');
        const message = interaction.options.getString('message');
        const mentionEveryone = interaction.options.getBoolean('mention_everyone') ?? false;

        try {
            await channel.send(mentionEveryone ? `@everyone \n\n${message}` : message);
            await interaction.reply(`Announcement sent successfully in <#${channel.id}>`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply('An error occurred while trying to send the announcement.');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: _"I've been having an issue"_ is not really helpful.

Comment: Did you mean to use `getChannel()` instead of `.get()` when defining `channel`?

Comment: Please show expected results and actual results.  Please indicate what logs you have checked, and why they are not helpful toward a solution.